# Grunt build with requirejs plugins in the code

Tags: requirejs, gruntjs, grunt-contrib-requirejs

I am using the `goog` plugin for requirejs like this:

```
define(['underscore', 'backbone', 'marionette', 'goog!visualization,1,packages:[geomap]'],
function(_, Backbone, Marionette) {
        ...
});
```

The code works fine until I build the project using grunt (`grunt build`). When I run the built code, I get `Uncaught ReferenceError: google is not defined` error. My Gruntfile.js includes this:

```
requirejs: {
  build: {
    options: {
      baseUrl: "js/",
      optimizeCss: 'none',
      mainConfigFile: "js/app.js",
      name: "../bower_components/almond/almond",
      out: "build/js/app-built.js",
      include: ["app"]
    }
  }
},
```

I tried adding the pluging to the `include` part but no luck. Is there a way to fix it?

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried including the `goog` javascript file in the requirejs configuration? My configurations has the following in the requirejs configuration and it works.

```
require({
  paths : {
    goog : 'bower_components/src/goog.js'
  }
});
```